# Элемент select и rtl-язык

Tags: css, rtl

[image: Элемент select в rtl-языкаx]

Для элемента `select` значок выпадающего списка находится справа. При создании стилей для поддержки `rtl`-языков получается вот такое наложение текста на значок, как на рисунке.

Подскажите, расположение значка выпадающего списка у `select` всегда справа? Или же оно зависит, например, от языка ОС?

Comment: [может поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681955/html-select-and-option-mixed-directions-ltr-rtl?answer=27464717),  [habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/company/alconost/blog/250061/)

Answer (score 0):

Не самое изящное решение, но все же.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPjVRr

```css
select {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  padding-left: 140px;
}

div {
    position:absolute;
    content: '>';
    width:15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color:blue;
    left: 9px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: .85em;
}
```

```html
<div>></div>
<select>
  <option>Пункт 1</option>
  <option>Пункт 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Вопрос не в том, как для `rtl`-языков изменить положение значка, а в том, нужно ли вообще это делать. У меня возникло предположение, что в ОС с `rtl`-языком этот значок, возможно, располагается слева по умолчанию (как у нас справа). И тогда вообще ничего править не нужно. Но так ли это?

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте смените аттрибут lang у html на значени rtl языка.

Comment: Смена атрибута `lang` у `html` ничего не дала: значок по-прежнему справа.

Comment: Комментарий выше относится к Opera. Как оказалось, в Firefox, если атрибут `lang` в `html` соответствует `rtl`-языку,  значок находится слева, и никакого наложения, соответственно, нет.